# SQL in Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have 2 tables in an MS Access 2013 database that I have pulled through an ODBC. One is called `PUBLIC_PHONE_NUMBERS` and the 2nd is `PUBLIC_CUSTOMER`. Now I need to join the two fields `PHONE_ACCT` and `PHONE_NUMBER` from the phone table to the customer table. The phone account number is the same as the customer account number, but I need each account to have its phone number listed on the customer's table as well.

Here is what I thought would work:

```
SELECT public_phone_numbers.phone_acct, public_phone_numbers.phone_number
FROM public_phone_numbers
INNER JOIN public_customer
ON public_phone_numbers.phone_acct = public_customer.c_acct;
```

Comment: Also, don't tag MySQL and ms-access in the same question. The two are very different.

Comment: @McAdam331 re: [mysql] tag, see discussion on Meta [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275170/2144390).

Comment: @GordThompson I saw that. Certainly people can stop and look, though?

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understand what you need, but perhaps it's only a left outer join?

```
SELECT c.*, p.phone_number
FROM public_customer c 
left outer JOIN public_phone_numbers p
ON c.c_acct = p.phone_acct
```